# How do I configure my Linux Samba server smb.conf file to allow for Windows guest-access without requiring credentials from the server?

Tags: linux, network-shares, samba

How do I configure my Linux Samba server smb.conf file to allow for Windows guest-access without requiring credentials from the server?

I've tried the following smb.conf. It allows Windows clients to access the share and write and read as if root, **except** the Windows explorer prompts the user for credentials. That  means I have enter credential and option to store them for the root user on the Windows machine. I'd rather it just allow access without credentials being prompted for like I was able to set up in TrueNAS somehow.

This is a private, closed access network. I'd appreciate if someone call look at this smb.conf set up and tell me where I'm going wrong in what I'm trying to do. I'd like it to just allow anyone on the network subnet to access the smb share without credentials, yet still have the stored files forced to be owner:group root/root.

```
root@samba:~# cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   guest account = nobody
   allow insecure wide links = yes
   security = user
[ztank]
   follow symlinks = yes
   path = /mnt/ztank
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   wide links = yes
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 777
   directory mask = 777
   force user = root
   force group = root
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `map to guest` global option, typically setting it to `bad password`. This will allow SMB authentication to happen in the special "guest" mode without credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of `smb.conf` that can achieve passwordless access:

```
[global]
  workgroup = MyWorkGroup
  server string = Hello, use me
  security = user
  map to guest = Bad User
  guest account = <account-owning-folder>
  passdb backend = tdbsam
  
[the_public_share]
   path = /mysmbshare
   writable = yes
   printable = no
   public = yes
```

Reference :
[How to make Samba share to NOT ASK FOR PASSWORD](https://serverfault.com/questions/630631/how-to-make-samba-share-to-not-ask-for-password/828067#828067).